# Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.Error Coming

Tags: codeigniter

**codeighter controller**

```
 public function testemail()
    {
     
        $this->load->library('email');
        
        $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host']    = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port']    = '587';
        $config['smtp_user']    = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass']    = 'mygmailpassword';
        $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
        $config['validation'] = FALSE;
       

        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com','Admin');
        $this->email->to('reciever@gmail.com'); 
        $this->email->subject('Online Application Submitted');
        $this->email->message('Testing whether online application submitted');

        $send = $this->email->send();
        if($send) {
            echo "sent";
        } else {
             echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            
        }
}
```

**I used this code in codeighter but it's not working. it shows "Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method." this error why is that?**

Comment: *Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method*, is this code running on a shared server?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

public function testemail()
{

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    
   
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'mygmailpassword';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


    $this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com','Admin');
    $this->email->to('reciever@gmail.com'); 
    $this->email->subject('Online Application Submitted');
    $this->email->message('Testing whether online application submitted');

    $send = $this->email->send();
    if($send) {
        echo "sent";
    } else {
         echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        
    }
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).